# How to rollback flushed hibernate object in spring managed transaction

Tags: spring-transactions

In spring managed transaction i save a object using criteria,

```
MyObject ob = ...
getCurrentSession.save(ob);
```

after some i need to execute a update(HQL) query and in all those updated rows i need to update MyObject reference(ob).

while i try this i got "integrity constrains, no parent key " exception.

As a solution i done below,

```
MyObject ob = ...
getCurrentSession.save(ob);
getCurreentSession.flush();
```

then execute the update query and pass ref:ob to that.

works fine. But the problem is if update returns 0, i need to rollback my transaction. 
Note: i should not throw exception.

Since i am inside spring managed below are my approaches,

1) TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly(). this did not work. 
2) manually i deleted the persisted object. This works fine.

Just want to know that is there any way to rollback all my transaction?